# Show that $\mathbb F_q/\mathbb F_p$ is Galoisienne where $q=p^n$.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

> Show that $\mathbb F_q/\mathbb F_p$ is Galoisienne where $p$ is prime and $q=p^n$ and find his Galois group. I recall that $\mathbb F_p=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

I can't find any separable polynomial on $\mathbb F_p$ that split over $\mathbb F_q$. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Don't you know that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is (somehow by definition) the splitting field of $X^q-X$? This is so standard, that I hardly believe that you don't know this.

Comment: I didn't know that. Sorry. But How do you prove it ? $X^q-X=X(X^{p^n-1}-1)$ and how can I prove that $X^{p^n-1}-1$ is separable and split over $\mathbb F_q$ ?

Comment: You can find info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness

Answer (score 2):

$X^q-X$ would do it, since its formal derivatives is $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.